# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/FormatFeature in Swagger Response Validator

Tags: java, swagger

I am working with Atlasssian swagger-request-validator and i got the following error while running the application.

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/FormatFeature
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.<clinit>(YAMLFactory.java:29)
at io.swagger.v3.parser.ObjectMapperFactory.createYaml(ObjectMapperFactory.java:24)
at io.swagger.v3.parser.ObjectMapperFactory.createYaml(ObjectMapperFactory.java:20)
at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.<clinit>(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:36)
at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.getExtensions(OpenAPIParser.java:49)
at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:18)
at com.atlassian.oai.validator.SwaggerRequestResponseValidator.<init>(SwaggerRequestResponseValidator.java:112)
at com.atlassian.oai.validator.SwaggerRequestResponseValidator.<init>(SwaggerRequestResponseValidator.java:41)
at com.atlassian.oai.validator.SwaggerRequestResponseValidator$Builder.build(SwaggerRequestResponseValidator.java:335)
at Validator.main(Validator.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.FormatFeature
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 22 more
```

Why am I getting this error?
I referenced this https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/3d42d9c51a59b96f148df6aaa9ade8a0c216f3e4/swagger-request-validator-core/?at=master

Comment: Your CLASSPATH doesn't include the path where these classes are  placed.

Comment: try to refresh your maven/gradle project

Comment: How can I add them to the CLASSPATH

Comment: Depends on your project. Is this a maven project?

Comment: If you are facing this issue and in case using eclipse you can just right click project and select buildpath and add external jars.or for runtime you have to put them in to your application server.

Comment: Yes its a maven project